# Fiber cement fascia cracked at joint - how do I patch this?

Tags: repair, crack, cement, fascia

I have a cracked corner of fascia where two fiber cement boards meet. How would I go about fixing this? I tried "DAP Platinum Patch" spackling compound, just to find out that it's supposed to only cover minor cracks up to 1/8" deep.

I feel like this corner needs to be filled with something. What should I use?

[image]

Comment: Commenting because I don't know if this idea is bunkum: Try auto body filler, like "Bondo". Apply in layers, perhaps, per the instructions, but build out until the surface is proud of the facia faces, then sand flush, prime & paint. The stuff is good for outside work, since it's designed for cars. The existing pieces need to be dust- and dirt-free, so the filler has something solid to bind to.

Comment: Remove broken trim. Replace with new pieces.

Comment: Do you know why it cracked?

Comment: @JACK I think previous owner may have damaged it when installing the gazebo, you can see one of the roof support rods sticking in that direction. It is not degrading further.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a crisp corner, treat it like a plastering [spackle?] task but using exterior-grade filler.

Square off the corner by using a piece of exterior angle-bead held in place by a couple of dollops of your filler [knock it back a little if you need, to bed it properly], then smooth finish afterwards, leaving the metal edge as your visible corner. Paint as desired.
Done like this it will even be slightly resistant to a little movement afterwards [but not a lot].

[image]

[Examples of various bead types from UK trade store](https://www.wickes.co.uk/Products/Building-Materials/Plaster+Plasterboard/Angle-Bead/c/1000223). I don't know if the US uses the same naming conventions.

Comment: Ah, sounds like a great idea!